# python IDLE debugger self variable

Tags: python, debugging, python-idle

Is there some way to monitor self.{name} while debugging without the extra line below and also does someone has idea (good practice) how to omit the self. part in the code (after line 4 in the body of the other methods), it will make it more readable?

```
class QuickFindUf(object):

    def __init__(self, n):
        self._id = []

        for i in xrange(n):
            self._id.append(i)

    def connected(self, p, q):
        return self._id[p] == self._id[q]

    def union(self, p, q):
        pid = self._id[p]
        qid = self._id[q]

        l = self._id # debug only

        for i in xrange(len(self._id)):
            if self._id[i] == pid: 
                self._id[i] = qid
```

Comment: Objects don't have names, they just have references. Moreover, Python requires specifying self.

Comment: Thanks, the self part is obvious, the question is for some kind of workaround after line 4. P.S. Good point anyway, I've added the clarification in the qn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since n in needed later, save it.  As far as I can see, `__init__` sets self._id to range(n) (list(range(10) in 3.x), so the rest can be condensed.

```
def __init__(self, n):
    self.n = n
    self._id = range(n)  # list(range(n)) in 3.x.
```

In any case, looking up an attribute of self just once in a method, as in `l = self._id` and using the direct reverence, here l, thereafter, is standard practice, not a workaround or debug-only thing.  I would write union as follows:

```
def union(self, p, q):
    l = self._id
    pid = l[p]
    qid = l[q]
    for i in xrange(n):
        if l[i] == pid: 
            l[i] = qid
```

You might consider what to do if p or q are out of range.  Do you have some other question?

Comment: Thanks, Terry. Local name for self._id is good then. About the range, do you mean that I don't need xrange since I am creating the list just once? I've read somewhere that xrange is the default implementation in Python 3.x

Comment: P.S. I got it, you mean that the equivalent in 3.x is just rage and use the list constructor. I'll need another list with value 1 for all indexes for the weighted version so I might stick with the for loop.

Comment: For a list of 1s, `3 * [1] == [1, 1, 1]`, etc.

Comment: hah, good one :) thanks, I might change my code n * [1], looks clean